# Is loading data into static memory of functions before using it bad practice?

Tags: c

The title might not convey what I mean clearly, so let me give you an example:

```
void myFunc (char * str) {
    static char * str_inside;

    // Load data into the static variable
    if (str != NULL) {
        str_inside = str;
        return;
    }

    /* do stuff with str_inside in consecutive calls */
}

void doStuff () {
    // Calls the function, which has data already loaded
    myFunc (NULL);
}

int main () {
    char str[] = "Hello!";

    // Load data into the function
    myFunc (str);

    doStuff ();
}
```

The reason for this being that doStuff might not have access to the original string. For example when working with asynchronous event handling in a GUI application.

Is this considered bad practice/does it expose risks?

Comment: For multithreading, static always poses a problem, as there is risk of concurrent access.

Comment: It looks only moderately evil to me, kinda like a hidden global:)   I would never do this, (I never use 'static' at all anyway, it's just messy and there is the threads issue as noted by Sven).

Comment: Besides the reentracy problem mentioned above, the user of `doStuff()` has to know a) that `myFunc()` has been previously called with a valid, non-null argument, and b) the size of the buffer last passed to `myFunc()`. Kinda risky.

Comment: Also, a memory leak may occur if multiple calls to `myFunc()` are made with pointers to dynamically allocated memory. Not a problem in the example.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this considered bad practice/does it expose risks?

This is a bad practice (as written) for at least two reasons:

- it is thread-hostile -- there is no way to use `myFunc` safely in a multi-threaded program
- it can easily result in using a dangling pointer.

Consider:

```
void foo()
{
  char c[] = "Hello";
  myFunc(c);
}
```

If `foo` is the first call to `myFunc`, then `myFunc` will retain a pointer to `c`, which will be invalid as soon as `foo` returns.

To make this slightly safer (but still thread-hostile), you can make a copy of the `str`:

```
void myFunc (char * str) {
    static char * str_inside;

    // Load data into the static variable
    if (str != NULL) {
        str_inside = strdup(str);
        return;
    }
...
```

To make this thread-compatible (at least for modern `C` versions), do this:

```
void myFunc (char * str) {
    static char * str_inside = strdup(str);  // strdup only called once.
...
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is loading data into static memory of functions before using it bad practice?

It is OK practice when

- When the loading into static data, the (`=`), is sufficient to copy all the needed data for the life of code.  Copying a pointer is a problem as the valid lifetime of the pointer is typically limited and of what it points to tends to not last the lifetime of code.
- With multithreading, reading the static variable needs to be done in a manner that prevents concurrent access.